# Concatenate with NULL values ( Should not replace NULL )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, null, string-manipulation

After some time searching for an answer, I got a LOT of question saying to use `coalesce`,`concat()`, and etc, but what I need is:

Table:

```
create table nulos ( nome varchar(max))
alter table nulos add cidade varchar(max)
```

values:

```
insert into nulos values ( 'rafael','são paulo'),('juliana',null)
```

I need to concatenate the values inside this table, to a insert, like this:

```
 select 'insert into nulos (nome,cidade) values ('+nome+','+cidade+')'
from nulos
```

And the result of the select:

```
insert into nulos (nome,cidade) values (rafael,são paulo)
NULL
```

how can I use the NULL value inside this concatenation? every answer says something to replace the null with `''` or `'_'`, But what I need it this:

```
insert into nulos (nome,cidade) values (rafael,são paulo)

insert into nulos (nome,cidade) values (Juliana,NULL)
```

`SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL on` is not an option because it just deletes the NULL value, and I need to insert it.

Comment: What is the context for this?  you should be using parameterised queries if this is going anywhere near production.

Comment: Do you need `insert into nulos (nome,cidade) values (Juliana,NULL)` in the result? Or `insert into nulos (nome,cidade) values ('Juliana',NULL)`?

Comment: Why are you constructing dynamic queries here? *Please* tell me this isn't user input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your strings in single quotes so they will be input as strings.  The NULL does not need quotes.

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO nulos (nome,cidade) VALUES (' +
    CASE WHEN nome is null then 'NULL' ELSE ''''+
        REPLACE(nome,'''','''''')+'''' END + 
    ',' +
    CASE WHEN cidade is null then 'NULL' ELSE ''''+
        REPLACE(cidade,'''','''''')+'''' END +
    ')'
FROM nulos
```

This will give you:

```
INSERT INTO nulos (nome,cidade) VALUES ('rafael','são paulo')
INSERT INTO nulos (nome,cidade) VALUES ('Juliana',NULL)
```

Comment: @RacerSQL as long as none of your names are `O'Brien` Or [Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I added escaping for O'Brien.  As far as the ; I didn't code for that because it wasn't part of the question but I agree that would be a whole other problem.  I only do this (above) when scripting inserts from already cleaned data but yeah, it should not be used for unprotected inputs like front end apps.

Comment: As long as the quote is escaped correctly the second one (bobby tables) won't actually cause a problem either. The problem is the unescaped quote closes off the string literal there too. There are potential problems with homoglyph smuggling but not as written here.

Comment: Oh yeah I've added the replace for it. Thanks both of you